# ECS not scaling down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

I have a problem with ECS not scaling if someone could help me with that would be great.
I have

- 1 cluster
- 1 service
- min tasks = 1
- desired tasks = 1
- max tasks = 4
- Protection from scale in disabled
- ASG with ECSManaged: true
- ASG with memory: Tracking ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization at 70 (scale in: on) and cpu: Tracking ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization at 30 (scale in: on)
- 1 Capacity provider
- Capacity provider weight 1
- Capacity provider base 0

If my service scales out to 3 tasks from example, it stays that way without scaling in even if both cloudwatch alarms are on.

If I change the desired # of tasks manually to 1, it stays that way until it scales to 3 but never scales down even if it could.

What could I be missing?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the docs are here if you haven't read them yet: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html and I recall scaling down taking some time but I don't remember how long. I would expect scale down to take an hour, but I don't have any evidence for that.

Comment: I would start by looking at the alerts in CloudWatch that are created by the autoscaling service. You will be able to see a graph of the metric each alert is tracking, and the current state of each alert (in alarm, or OK). My guess is your CPU usage may be higher than you expect, so it has to scale out multiple tasks to get to 30% average CPU utilization, but whatever the cause, you should be able to see what is going on based on those alerts in CloudWatch. If it still doesn't make sense after looking at those, edit your question to include the alert details.